# Convert numbers stored as strings from array of objects using jq?

Tags: jq

Given an array of json objects such as

```js
[
{
  "firstName": "Charles",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": "65",
  "postalCode": "943",
  "habitants": "5"
},
{
  "firstName": "Charles",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 41,
  "postalCode": "94103",
  "habitants": "2"
},
{
  "firstName": "Charles",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 23,
  "postalCode": "94103",
  "habitants": "3",
  "animals": "1"
}
]
```

How to make sure all numbers are converted back to numbers ? (without corrupting rightful strings)

Note: other stackoverflow question don't answer this question, neither can ChatGPT.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this generically for any object, as in detect if a string matches a number format? If so, you could probably do it by testing values against a [regex](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE), depending onw what you consider a "number" (since "1e6" and 0x555 are valid numbers). Or it it acceptable to hard code the key names you want to parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `walk` through the document tree, and `if` you encounter a string `type`, try to convert it `tonumber`. If it fails (`?`), leave it as it was (`// .`). Likewise, if it wasn't a string in the first place (`else .`).

```bash
walk(if type == "string" then tonumber? // . else . end)
```

```json
[
  {
    "firstName": "Charles",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 65,
    "postalCode": 943,
    "habitants": 5
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Charles",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 41,
    "postalCode": 94103,
    "habitants": 2
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Charles",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 23,
    "postalCode": 94103,
    "habitants": 3,
    "animals": 1
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uX-Nn7kpMUj)

Comment: works! thank you. You helped a language conservation project https://hugolpz.github.io/LanguagesGallery/ !